# Add line break to input value

Tags: jquery, forms, email, input

I have this line within a jQuery function:

`$(".text-input").val("text in first line - text in second line");`

The `input` belongs to a form which is sent after being submitted.

**EDIT:** I use the wordpress plugin contact form 7 for it and the input I have the issue with is a radio button. Contact form 7 supports a so-called "html content type" and also when this is activated, the `<br>`-tag does not work.

Is it possible to add a line break which shows up in the mail?

I already tried

```
\n
\r\n
&#10;
&#x00A;
```

**EDIT:** ...and also `<br>` in combination with the "html content type" of contact form 7...

But none of these work. Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure you can add line breaks in an input.. try a textarea (assuming .text-input is an input element)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @YotamOmer , try substituting `textarea` element for `input` element

```js
$("textarea").val("a\nb" );

console.log($("textarea").val());

$("<pre>").text($("textarea").val()).appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Replacing the input with a textarea is not an option because it has to be a radio button. For now I've found a way to avoid this issue and will come back to it later when there is more time for it. Thank you very much for your... input. :)

Comment: @Thorin  _"Replacing the input with a textarea is not an option because it has to be a radio button."_ ? Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? _"radio button"_ `html` not appear at Question ? "For now I've found a way to avoid this issue and will come back to it later when there is more time for it."_ If Question resolved, can post Answer found ? accept own Answer ?, close Question ?

Comment: When I was framing the question I wasn't aware that it is important that the input is a radio button, sorry. I now edited the question. It is not resolved and I don't have an answer to it.

Comment: I'm sorry I spent an hour or so in trying to reproduce the issue with a fiddle but had no success. I think the problem has got to do with how contact form 7 processes the input data or something like that. I was working on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Thorin2/g1amdxp0/5/ but it's an html output so <br> will work in the fiddle but with contact form 7 it's not html output and <br> does not work. Maybe it's impossible for you to find a solution without knowing much more of the code which is used. Might be better to close the question? How do I do that?

Comment: @Thorin http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252496/how-to-close-mark-as-resolved-my-question-i-have-found-an-answer-to ?

Comment: I read the link and it seems helpful: "Otherwise a vote to close with the  '...not reproducable or typo error...' reason is all you can do." I think I would like to do that but I have no idea how it works?

Comment: @Thorin See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Comment: Thank you! I think the best I can do is to delete the question. Sorry for having wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use html `</br>` in your jQuery code as follows:

```
$(".text-input").val("text in first line </br> text in second line");
```

and set email format to HTML as follows

```
$mail->IsHTML( true ); // Set emails format to HTML in PHP
```

Hope it helps....!

Comment: Maybe I should have added that I use contact form 7 and enabled "html content type". In this case <br> does not work. Does the "html content type" the same as $mail->IsHTML( true ); ? If not then I don't know where to put this line, can you help me?

Comment: May be this link will help you in adding html content in contact form 7 https://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-html-content-type-how-to-style